# Android Studio Handler issue

Tags: java, android, timer, handler

```
    Runnable job = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            randomNumber = rand.nextInt(99) + 1;
            arrayList.add(randomNumber);
            textArrayList.setText("" + arrayList);
            textRandomNumber.setText("" + randomNumber);
            if (gameOptionNumber < arrayList.size())
            {
                layoutGameButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
    };
    mHandler.post(job);
```

...

```
    else if(v == buttonEnter)
    {
        if(output.getText().length() != 0)
        {
            temp = Integer.parseInt(output.getText().toString());
            compareNumber(temp);
            output.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Here the the textview changes every 3 seconds and I have to enter what the previous number was. The number keep changes every 3 seconds, but it should stop when the user doesn't press any button within 3 seconds before the number changes. Is there a statement that I can call in handler, such as `mHandler.cancel()` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this way:

```
private Handler handler;
private Runnable job;
```

When you need to stop posting runnable:

```
if(handler!=null){
   handler.removeCallbacks(job);
}
```

Also add code on **onStop**:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
 super.onStop();
   if(handler!=null){
       handler.removeCallbacks(job);
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: When I put those code it says cannot resolve symbol 'job'

Comment: Thanks in advance! I would also appreciate if you would be able to answer this one too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377003/android-studio-handler-removecallback-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

You need to Remove your callback from your handler:

Check condition and remove call back

```
handler.removeCallbacks(job);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(job); 
mHandler.postDelayed(job, 3000);
```

this will remove pending callbacks for this runnable and add a latest one. If user doesn't press for more than 3 seconds it will post the runnable and will do the work.